# AVMutableVideoComposition some inserted video crash composition

Tags: iphone, video, avfoundation

Some videos play fine alone as simple `AVAssets` but when inserted in an `AVMutableVideoComposition` they make the whole composition fail even if those videos are inserted alone in an empty composition. Anyone has similar issues? Sometime re-encoding the videos before inserting them makes it work sometime not.  I can't see any mistake in my timing instruction and using some other video don't cause any problem at all no matter their length. Can there be issues with the number of frame or the duration of the asset or their format? (all are h264 single track)

Answer (score 0):

Well indeed it looks like some video may cause problem when being inserted. example here duration of the track is the issue.

```
AVAsset * video           = ...;
NSArray * videoTracks     = [video tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVAssetTrack * videoTrack = videoTracks.firstObject; 
CMTime duration           = videoTrack.timeRange.duration // this time cause error

AVMutableCompositionTrack * track = ...;
CMTime insertCMTime    = kCMTimeZero;
CMTimeRange trackRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration);
    [track insertTimeRange:trackRange
                   ofTrack:videoTrack
                    atTime:insertCMTime
                     error:nil];
```

Trimming the range to insert to a round second solved the problem for all video tested so far

```
NSTimeInterval interval   = (int)CMTimeGetSeconds(videoTrack.timeRange.duration);
CMTime roundedDuration    = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(interval, 60000);
```